# Unable to get authorization token of a User

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

In my django-rest-application, I successfully register a user using post method. However, when I am trying to login or get the Authorization token for the user I am getting unauthorize error.

I am updating Token database using the post_save receiver as below.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def create_auth_token(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Token.objects.create(user=instance)
```

Even when I am checking the model in the python shell I could successfully verify the user and token data by the following method.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token

user = User.objects.get(username='user1')
token = Token.objects.get(user__username='user1')
```

The user.password and token data are verified and exist. And the user is active. However, I could not able to get the authorization token using curl method. Even I am not able login in the browser using the credentials.

Curl request

```
curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api-token-auth/ -d "username=user1&password=password"
```

My settings.py file is given below.

```
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'c8x*pc%c$0-_k-wx5&u42m3k8k1jv!^o27&-*1w3u*v!ut3-5b'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Rest Framework app
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    # Internal Apps
    'src.main',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',

    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    )
}
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
ROOT_URLCONF = 'market_place.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'market_place.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Where am I missing?

**Edits**
Error with the curl command

```
{
    "non_field_errors": [
        "Unable to log in with provided credentials."
    ]
}
```

My User profile model is below:

```
class UserProfileModel(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profile_image = models.ImageField(upload_to="user_profile_pic", null=True)




class UserProfileRegisterView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserProfileSerializer

    permission_classes = [
        permissions.AllowAny  # Or anon users can't register
    ]
```

Comment: There is no problem with your curl command. I applied on my system and getting the token.If you are unable to login with your credentials that means there is some problem with your credentials. Can you please share the code how you are registering the user?

Comment: What is the error you get? post it. And again, the token should be created during login, not when the user is created. A user can several tokens depending on how many devices he is logged in with

Comment: Is the login(or auth-token) view a custom one or the one from DRF? post the code if it is a custom view

Comment: For login, I was trying to make an API request in the browser. The viewsets is  having permission for an authorized user only. Hence the browser popup a login page. I was providing credential there. I do not have any view sets for login.

Comment: For auth-toke I am using view from rest_framework.authtoken.views obtain_auth_token.

Comment: The obtain_auth_token view already creates tokens during login, so you don't need to create it yourself after user creation. You most likely are not saving the password correctly during the user creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you posted is all there is to your user creation view, then that is where the issue is. Passwords are not stored in their plain form in Django for obvious security reasons. Instead, their hash is stored and during login, the hash of the input password is compared to the stored hash.

From the code you posted, it seems the password is stored in it's plain form, therefore when the authenticator tries to compare the hash of the password sent and the stored input, they do not match.

You should use the `user.set_password()` to ensure it is properly hashed and saved.

Here is what the `create()` method of your `UserProfileSerializer` should look like:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    password = validated_data.pop('password')
    instance = super().create(validated_data)
    instance.user.set_password(password)

    instance.user.save()
    return instance
```

Of course the details of how the profile and user are created are beyond the scope of this code as I don't know how your `UserProfileSerializer` is defined, but this should give you the general idea.
If you are creating the user object at the same time as the profile, then the create method will look a little bit more complex. Check DRF's [writable nested serializers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#writable-nested-representations) for details on how to achieve that

Comment: Thanks Ken4scholars. I got where I was doing the mistake.  This is working perfectly.